# How can i solve Type Error in using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, error-handling

Why ı got a error? Could you help and modify my code please?

-TypeError: object of type <class 'float'> cannot be safely interpreted as an integer.

-TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x):
    return x**3-2*x
def inputNumber(message):
     while True:
        try:
           userInput =float(input(message))  
        except ValueError:
           print("Enter valid")
           continue
        else:
           return userInput 
           break
 

interval1=float(inputNumber("Please write lower bound: "))
interval=float(inputNumber("Please write upper bound: "))
stepsize=float(inputNumber("Enter a step size: "))

x = np.linspace(float(interval1),float(interval),float(stepsize))
y = f(x)
```

Comment: Why are you using `float(stepsize)`?  The docs say the step is supposed to be an integer!

Answer (score 0):

The first three arguments of `linspace` are the start, end, and the number of samples to generate - not the step size. Try `np.arange(interval1, interval, stepsize)`.

Alternatively, you could calculate the number of samples with: `num = round((interval-interval1) / stepsize)` and then plug that into linspace: `np.linspace(interval1, interval, num)`, but I do not recommend using this instead of `arange`.